# Html 5 canvas cars speed

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

In function setupGameData() I have parametars for 2 cars. In first car speed is 3.00 and second car speed is 3.50. If you click on button "Watch race" you can see first car 3.00 is faster than second car 3.50. How to repair code to see 3.50 is faster than 3.00.

```js
/*jslint plusplus: true, sloppy: true, indent: 4 */
(function () {
    "use strict";
    // this function is strict...
}());

// RequestAnimFrame: a browser API for getting smooth animations
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

// Globals
var canvas = null,
    ctx = null,
    background = null,
    car_sprite = null,
    game_data = null,
    CAR_WIDTH = 170,
    CAR_HEIGHT = 37,
    STEP_COUNT_MILLISECONDS =  1000 / 30,
    RACE_LENGTH = 20,
    RACE_FINISH_LINE_X = 770,
    iTime = 0,
    iFinishPlace = 1,
    random_graph;

function clearCanvas() {

    // clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
}

function drawBackground() {

    clearCanvas();
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, -400);

    loadCarSprite();
}

function loadBackground() {

    // Load the timer
    background = new Image();
    background.src = 'http://www.upslike.net/imgdb/race-scence-f7bf19.png';
    background.onload = drawBackground;
}

function setupGameData() {

    var json =
    {
        cars:
        [
            {
                "colour": 'blue',
                "x": 0,
                "y": 50,
                "spritex": 0,
                "spritey": 0,
                "graph": null,
                "step": 77,
                "position": null,
                "speed": 3.00,
                "speed_late": 0.28            },
            {
                "colour": 'red',
                "x": 0,
                "y": 110,
                "spritex": 0,
                "spritey": 37,
                "graph": null,
                "step": 39,
                "position": null,
                "speed": 3.50,
                "speed_late": 0.48          }
        ],
        graphs:
        [
            [0,5,10,20,40,60,70],
            [0,10,20,30,40,50,60],
            [0,20,39,40,50,55,58],
            [0,10,20,30,40,50,55],
            [0,25,45,47,49,50,52],
            [0,10,20,29,38,45,50],
            [0,15,20,25,30,40,45],
            [0,2,4,8,20,30,40],
            [0,5,10,15,20,25,30],
            [0,1,3,14,15,22,30],
            [0,5,11,14,17,22,25],
            [0,20,30,44,67,72,90],
            [0,2,7,24,47,52,65],
            [0,2,9,20,40,52,70]
        ]
    };

    random_graph = Math.floor( Math.random() * json.graphs.length );

    return json;    
}

function drawCar(car) {

    // Draw the car onto the canvas

    ctx.drawImage(car_sprite,
        car.spritex, car.spritey,
        CAR_WIDTH, CAR_HEIGHT,
        car.x-70 + car.step, car.y,
        CAR_WIDTH, CAR_HEIGHT);

     drawText(car);
}

function drawCars() {

    var iCarCounter;

    for(iCarCounter = 0; iCarCounter < game_data.cars.length; iCarCounter++) {

        drawCar(game_data.cars[iCarCounter]);
    }
}

function initCar(current_car) {

    current_car.graph = random_graph;

}

function initGameState() {

    var iCarCounter;

    for(iCarCounter = 0; iCarCounter < game_data.cars.length; iCarCounter++) {

        initCar(game_data.cars[iCarCounter]);

    }
}

function getPositionAtTime(graph_index, percentageElapsed, current_car) {

    var graph = game_data.graphs[graph_index],
        iNumberOfGraphPoints = graph.length,
        iGraphPosition = null,
        iFloor = null,
        iCeil = null,
        p = null;
        position = null;

    graph = graph.map( function( val, i ) {

        if ( i === 0 ) {

            return val;

        }

        var car_speed = undefined === current_car.speed ? 1 : current_car.speed,
            car_speed_late = undefined === current_car.speed_late ? car_speed : current_car.speed_late;

        return ( i < Math.floor( graph.length / 2 ) ) ? car_speed : car_speed_late;

    });

    iGraphPosition = (iNumberOfGraphPoints / 100) * percentageElapsed;

    iFloor = Math.floor(iGraphPosition);
    iCeil = Math.ceil(iGraphPosition);

    if(iGraphPosition === iFloor) {

        position = graph[iFloor];

    } else if(iGraphPosition === iCeil) {

        position = graph[iCeil];

    } else {

        p = (graph[iCeil] - graph[iFloor]) / 100;

        position = ((iGraphPosition - iFloor) * 100) * p + graph[iFloor];

    }

    return position;

}

function redrawRoadSection() {

    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 400, 1000, 200, 0, 0, 1000, 200);   
}

function graphPosToScreenPos() {

    return (900 / 100)  * (position / 60 * 100);   
}

function updateDebugWindow() {

  // Debug window
    var time = document.getElementById('time');

    if(time !== null)  {

       time.value = iTime / 1000;
    }

}


function drawText(current_car) {

    if(current_car.position !== null) {

        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.font = "normal 12px Facebook Letter Faces";
        ctx.strokeText(current_car.position, RACE_FINISH_LINE_X + current_car.step + 110, current_car.y + 25);

    }

}

function moveCar(iCarCounter) {

    var current_car =  game_data.cars[iCarCounter],
        seconds = iTime / 1000,
        percentageElapsed = (seconds / RACE_LENGTH) * 100,
        a = 20,
        velocity = 2,
        position = getPositionAtTime(current_car.graph, percentageElapsed,current_car);

    if(current_car.x < RACE_FINISH_LINE_X) {

        current_car.x =  graphPosToScreenPos(position) + (velocity * seconds) + (1/2 * a * Math.pow(seconds, 2));

    }
    else {

        current_car.x = RACE_FINISH_LINE_X;

        if(current_car.position === null) {

            current_car.position = iFinishPlace++;
        }
    }

    drawCar(current_car);
}

function initCars() {

    game_data = setupGameData();

    initGameState();
    drawCars();
}

function stopLoop() {

    iTime = 0;
    iFinishPlace = 1;
}


function startRace() {

    var iCarCounter;

    redrawRoadSection();

    for(iCarCounter = 0; iCarCounter < game_data.cars.length; iCarCounter++) {

        moveCar(iCarCounter);

    }

    updateDebugWindow();

    if(iFinishPlace > 4) {

        stopLoop();

    } else {

        iTime += STEP_COUNT_MILLISECONDS;

        requestAnimFrame(startRace);
    }
}

function startLoop() {

    stopLoop();

    requestAnimFrame(startRace);
}

function loadCarSprite() {

    // Load the timer
    car_sprite = new Image();
    car_sprite.src = 'http://www.upslike.net/imgdb/car-scene-53401b.png';
    car_sprite.onload = initCars;
}

function draw() {

        // Main entry point got the motion canvas example
        canvas = document.getElementById('motion');

        // Canvas supported?
        if (canvas.getContext) {

                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        loadBackground();

        } else {
                alert("Canvas not supported!");
        }
}
```

```html
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    draw();
}
</script>

        <center><canvas id="motion" width="1000px" height="200px"></canvas></center>                    
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left:65px;">
              <div id="alerter" class="hid">
                <input id="loop" onclick="javascript:initCars(); startLoop();" type="button" class="prikaz" value="Watch race">                                 
              </div>
              </div>
</br>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXOBby)

Comment: in moveCar you are *not* reading each car speed, but just using a constant velocity set to 2. Do you understand the code you provided ?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is use `console.log` in your car movement function to see what speed is, to me it looks like your car speed is being converted to an int instead of a double so your speed 3.50 is 3.00.

Also in your `moveCar` function you are setting the velocity to 2 and using that in your function, shouldn't you be using your `speed` variable?

Comment: How to convert in double. I think in JS variable is automatic double

Comment: Javascript is `duck typed` so it should be a double, however I would make sure to console.log `speed` and check to see if it is outputting 3.50 or 3, Also as I said above, it doesn't look like you are using speed.

Comment: Are you know how to putting into double If I put second car speed 4.5  first car is faster than second. first car have speed 3.00

Answer (score 0):

It is also depend on speed late(Json). If you increase blue car 'speed late' then blue car speed is fast. And increase red car 'speed late' then red car speed is fast.

```js
/*jslint plusplus: true, sloppy: true, indent: 4 */
(function () {
    "use strict";
    // this function is strict...
}());
 
// RequestAnimFrame: a browser API for getting smooth animations
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();
 
// Globals
var canvas = null,
    ctx = null,
    background = null,
    car_sprite = null,
    game_data = null,
    CAR_WIDTH = 170,
    CAR_HEIGHT = 37,
    STEP_COUNT_MILLISECONDS =  1000 / 30,
    RACE_LENGTH = 20,
    RACE_FINISH_LINE_X = 770,
    iTime = 0,
    iFinishPlace = 1,
    random_graph;
 
function clearCanvas() {
 
    // clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
}
 
function drawBackground() {
 
    clearCanvas();
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, -400);
   
    loadCarSprite();
}
 
function loadBackground() {
 
    // Load the timer
    background = new Image();
    background.src = 'http://www.upslike.net/imgdb/race-scence-f7bf19.png';
    background.onload = drawBackground;
}
 
function setupGameData() {
 
    var json =
    {
        cars:
        [
            {
                "colour": 'blue',
                "x": 0,
                "y": 50,
                "spritex": 0,
                "spritey": 0,
                "graph": null,
                "step": 77,
                "position": null,
                "speed": 3.55,
                "speed_late": 1           },
            {
                "colour": 'red',
                "x": 0,
                "y": 110,
                "spritex": 0,
                "spritey": 37,
                "graph": null,
                "step": 39,
                "position": null,
                "speed": 3.55,
                "speed_late": 19          }
        ],
        graphs:
        [
            [0,5,10,20,40,60,70],
            [0,10,20,30,40,50,60],
            [0,20,39,40,50,55,58],
            [0,10,20,30,40,50,55],
            [0,25,45,47,49,50,52],
            [0,10,20,29,38,45,50],
            [0,15,20,25,30,40,45],
            [0,2,4,8,20,30,40],
            [0,5,10,15,20,25,30],
            [0,1,3,14,15,22,30],
            [0,5,11,14,17,22,25],
            [0,20,30,44,67,72,90],
            [0,2,7,24,47,52,65],
            [0,2,9,20,40,52,70]
        ]
    };
 
    random_graph = Math.floor( Math.random() * json.graphs.length );
 
    return json;    
}
 
function drawCar(car) {
   
    // Draw the car onto the canvas
    
    ctx.drawImage(car_sprite,
        car.spritex, car.spritey,
        CAR_WIDTH, CAR_HEIGHT,
        car.x-70 + car.step, car.y,
        CAR_WIDTH, CAR_HEIGHT);
       
     drawText(car);
}
 
function drawCars() {
 
    var iCarCounter;
   
    for(iCarCounter = 0; iCarCounter < game_data.cars.length; iCarCounter++) {
       
        drawCar(game_data.cars[iCarCounter]);
    }
}
 
function initCar(current_car) {
   
    current_car.graph = random_graph;
       
}
 
function initGameState() {
 
    var iCarCounter;
   
    for(iCarCounter = 0; iCarCounter < game_data.cars.length; iCarCounter++) {
 
        initCar(game_data.cars[iCarCounter]);
 
    }
}
 
function getPositionAtTime(graph_index, percentageElapsed, current_car) {
       
    var graph = game_data.graphs[graph_index],
        iNumberOfGraphPoints = graph.length,
        iGraphPosition = null,
        iFloor = null,
        iCeil = null,
        p = null;
        position = null;
 
    graph = graph.map( function( val, i ) {
 
        if ( i === 0 ) {
 
            return val;
 
        }
 
        var car_speed = undefined === current_car.speed ? 1 : current_car.speed,
            car_speed_late = undefined === current_car.speed_late ? car_speed : current_car.speed_late;
 
        return ( i < Math.floor( graph.length / 2 ) ) ? car_speed : car_speed_late;
 
    });
 
    iGraphPosition = (iNumberOfGraphPoints / 100) * percentageElapsed;
   
    iFloor = Math.floor(iGraphPosition);
    iCeil = Math.ceil(iGraphPosition);
   
    if(iGraphPosition === iFloor) {
       
        position = graph[iFloor];
       
    } else if(iGraphPosition === iCeil) {
       
        position = graph[iCeil];
       
    } else {
               
        p = (graph[iCeil] - graph[iFloor]) / 100;
       
        position = ((iGraphPosition - iFloor) * 100) * p + graph[iFloor];
 
    }
 
    return position;
 
}
 
function redrawRoadSection() {
   
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 400, 1000, 200, 0, 0, 1000, 200);   
}
 
function graphPosToScreenPos() {
   
    return (900 / 100)  * (position / 60 * 100);   
}
 
function updateDebugWindow() {
 
  // Debug window
    var time = document.getElementById('time');
 
    if(time !== null)  {
       
       time.value = iTime / 1000;
    }
  
}
 
 
function drawText(current_car) {
 
    if(current_car.position !== null) {
       
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.font = "normal 12px Facebook Letter Faces";
        ctx.strokeText(current_car.position, RACE_FINISH_LINE_X + current_car.step + 110, current_car.y + 25);
   
    }
     
}
 
function moveCar(iCarCounter) {
 
    var current_car =  game_data.cars[iCarCounter],
        seconds = iTime / 1000,
        percentageElapsed = (seconds / RACE_LENGTH) * 100,
        a = 20,
        velocity = 2,
        position = getPositionAtTime(current_car.graph, percentageElapsed,current_car);
   
    if(current_car.x < RACE_FINISH_LINE_X) {
       
        current_car.x =  graphPosToScreenPos(position) + (velocity * seconds) + (1/2 * a * Math.pow(seconds, 2));
       
    }
    else {
       
        current_car.x = RACE_FINISH_LINE_X;
       
        if(current_car.position === null) {
           
            current_car.position = iFinishPlace++;
        }
    }
   
    drawCar(current_car);
}
 
function initCars() {
   
    game_data = setupGameData();
   
    initGameState();
    drawCars();
}
 
function stopLoop() {
 
    iTime = 0;
    iFinishPlace = 1;
}
 
 
function startRace() {
   
    var iCarCounter;
 
    redrawRoadSection();
   
    for(iCarCounter = 0; iCarCounter < game_data.cars.length; iCarCounter++) {
 
        moveCar(iCarCounter);
     
    }
 
    updateDebugWindow();
   
    if(iFinishPlace > 4) {
   
        stopLoop();
       
    } else {
       
        iTime += STEP_COUNT_MILLISECONDS;
   
        requestAnimFrame(startRace);
    }
}
 
function startLoop() {
   
    stopLoop();
   
    requestAnimFrame(startRace);
}
 
function loadCarSprite() {
 
    // Load the timer
    car_sprite = new Image();
    car_sprite.src = 'http://www.upslike.net/imgdb/car-scene-53401b.png';
    car_sprite.onload = initCars;
}
 
function draw() {
 
        // Main entry point got the motion canvas example
        canvas = document.getElementById('motion');
 
        // Canvas supported?
        if (canvas.getContext) {
           
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
        loadBackground();
 
        } else {
                alert("Canvas not supported!");
        }
}
```

```html
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    draw();
}
</script>
 
  <center><canvas id="motion" width="1000px" height="200px"></canvas></center>     
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left:65px;">
              <div id="alerter" class="hid">
                <input id="loop" onclick="javascript:initCars(); startLoop();" type="button" class="prikaz" value="Watch race">                                 
              </div>
              </div>
</br>
```

```
 'speed late':1
 'speed_late':19
```

good luck: